# Brightness too low in Debian Wheezy

Tags: debian, brightness

I have just installed Debian Wheezy in my Toshiba Laptop and it works great. However, sometimes the brightness level is too low when starting the system.

If I use the keys `Fn+F6` to decrease and `Fn+F7` to increase it, a bar appears in the screen, increasing or decreasing but the brightness level did not change.

Do you have any ideas?

PS: I'm using the gnome fallback mode.

Comment: exact model plz.  You might also post name of backlight driver(s).  `cd /sys/class/backlight; ls`

Comment: Hi! The laptop is a `Toshiba Satellite A500-140` and the video card is an `ATI Radeon HD 4500` . And in that directory you said, `ls -la` prints: `toshiba -> ../../devices/LNXSYSTM:00/LNXSYBUS:00/TOS1900:00/backlight/toshiba/`

Answer (score 6):

You might want to give this a try:

```
$ sudo echo 5 > /sys/class/backlight/acpi_video0/brightness
```

Change the value between 0-15 I believe to make it brighter or dimmer.

You might need to change these as well:

```
$ sudo echo 950 > /sys/class/backlight/intel_backlight/brightness
$ sudo echo 5 > /sys/class/backlight/acpi_video0/brightness
$ sudo echo 5 > /sys/class/backlight/acpi_video1/brightness
```

#### Changing brightness as a regular user

@JosephR. asked this folow-up in the comments and I thought it important enough to incorporate into my answer. If you want to expose this capbility to change brightness from the command line to regular users (the above `echo ... > /sys/...` is only accessible to root).

There is a package you can install called `xbacklight` which will allow user's to also change the brightness from the command line.

The package is available on Fedora and Ubuntu via repositories so just do either of these commands to install it:

```
# Ubuntu/Debian
$ sudo apt-get install xbacklight

# Fedora/CentOS
$ sudo yum install xbacklight
```

To use it:

```
# backlight 50%
$ xbacklight -set 50

# backlight 100%
$ xbacklight -set 100
```

#### xbacklight usage

```
$ xbacklight --help
usage: xbacklight [options]
  where options are:
  -display <display> or -d <display>
  -help
  -set <percentage> or = <percentage>
  -inc <percentage> or + <percentage>
  -dec <percentage> or - <percentage>
  -get
  -time <fade time in milliseconds>
  -steps <number of steps in fade>
```

#### How does user get elevated privileges to do this?

Again more follow-up to @JosephR. asking about this in a comment. It may seem like you as the user have elevated privileges to change the `/sys/class/backlight/...` when you use your laptops function keys (on my Thinkpad I use <kbd>Fn</kbd>+<kbd>Home</kbd> and <kbd>Fn</kbd>+<kbd>End</kbd> to change brightness). But you aren't really ever directly interacting with the `/sys/class/backlight/...` in the way that you think.

You're manipulating it indirectly through [D-Bus](http://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/dbus/). D-Bus is allowing you to manipulate this structure, `org.freedesktop.Hal.Device.KeyboardBacklight`, and [HAL](http://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/hal/) is allowing the privilege to do so. You can see this on my Fedora 14 system like this:

```
$ grep -i backlight /etc/dbus-1/system.d/*
/etc/dbus-1/system.d/hal.conf:         send_interface="org.freedesktop.Hal.Device.KeyboardBacklight"/>
/etc/dbus-1/system.d/hal.conf:         send_interface="org.freedesktop.Hal.Device.KeyboardBacklight"/>
```

In the file `hal.conf`:

```
  <!-- Only allow users at the local console to manipulate devices -->
  <policy at_console="true">
  ...
      <allow send_destination="org.freedesktop.Hal"
           send_interface="org.freedesktop.Hal.Device.KeyboardBacklight"/>
```

You can even mess with it from the command line via D-Bus like this. You can query the current value:

```
$ dbus-send \
     --print-reply \
     --system \
     --dest=org.freedesktop.Hal  \
     /org/freedesktop/Hal/devices/computer_backlight \
     org.freedesktop.Hal.Device.LaptopPanel.GetBrightness | \
     tail -1 | \
     awk '{print $2}'
```

Which returns the value:

```
15
```

Even cooler, you can mess with it like this (the bit `int32:10` below is setting brightness to "10"):

```
$ dbus-send \
     --print-reply \
     --system \
     --dest=org.freedesktop.Hal  \
     /org/freedesktop/Hal/devices/computer_backlight \
     org.freedesktop.Hal.Device.LaptopPanel.SetBrightness \
     int32:10 #2&>1 > /dev/null
```

You can see that we changed the brightness:

```
$ cat /sys/class/backlight/acpi_video0/brightness
10
```

#### References

- [Save brightness setting on reboot in Debian Squeeze / Wheezy](http://synapse.wordpress.com/2012/05/22/save-brightness-setting-on-reboot-in-debian-squeeze-wheezy/)
- [DBUS Backlight Brightness](http://wiki.ninjafocus.net/DBUS_Backlight_Brightness)

Comment: Hi! When trying the first line I got: `bash: /sys/class/backlight/acpi_video0/brightness: No such file or directory`. Inside `/sys/class/backlight` there is only a link named `toshiba` that points to `../../devices/LNXSYSTM:00/LNXSYBUS:00/TOS1900:00/backlight/toshiba/`

Comment: @KioMarv - is there anything under `/sys/class/backlight`?

Comment: +1 The range of accepted values is 0-15 on my Debian Wheezy.

Comment: @slm Do you happen to know if there's a wrapper/helper tool that lets you control brightness as a regular user?

Comment: @JosephR. you can use `xbacklight` to expose this capability to userspace.

Comment: @JosephR. - see updates to my answer, shows how to use it.

Comment: Interesting tool. I will give it a go. What I actually meant is: how come the regular user is allowed to change backlighting through (for example) a keyboard button but not through the command line?

Comment: @JosephR. - see my updates to answer. Does that answer your questions?

Comment: Perfect! Just what I was after. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Hi!! This week I don't have my laptop available (out of town). I'll try your solution ASAP. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Edit `/etc/default/grub` and add:

```
pcie_aspm=force acpi_backlight=vendor
```

after:

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"
```

After the changes, the whole line will look like this:

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash pcie_aspm=force acpi_backlight=vendor"
```

Comment: Please do not just paste links: include some detail so that the answer stands alone.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, and this was a simple solution for this ugly problem.
I installed `olpc` from the repositories of debian wheezy, then you can use two commands

```
 - sudo olpc-brightness up 
 - sudo olpc-brightness down
```

To allow key shortcuts, in the ***system configuration->keyboard configurations*** i did the two shortcuts.
Then you have to add this line

```
my_user ALL=  NOPASSWD: /usr/bin/olpc-brightness
```

at the end for the file */etc/sudoers* using an editor

```
sudo gedit /etc/sudoers
```

.This allow the command ***olpc-brightness*** change the file that stores the bright value.

Answer (score 0):

Try in the bootloader, passing the `nomodeset` argument to the kernel and removing `vt.handoff=X`